# Linked select lists in Google Form connected to Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, selectlist

I have a google sheet document with a tab « client » (Column A : name of the client) and a tab « project » (Column A : Name of the project, Column B : name of the client (select list with data validation)). Then I have a Google form where I want to display 2 select list : Clients and projects but the second list (projects) have to be updated when a client has been chosen to display only the projects of the selected client... how can I do that??

Answer (score 0):

To create a linked list, you can follow the next approach (for this example, I'll describe how to create the list within a Spreadsheet):

1. Create a new sheet; listing in one column the name of the client, and in the second column list all the projects for the client (use one row per project)
2. Create a Named Range for each of your clients, and select the range for all the projects that match the client's name.
3. Finally, declare a list in a cell with Data Validation as a list, with all the names of the clients.
4. In your code, you want to check the value on your list > look up for the named range with that value > create a new list based on the values in the ranged list.

   `function onEdit() {

   var aSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var aCell = aSheet.getActiveCell();
    var aColumn = aCell.getColumn();

   //Verify I am editing the list of clients
    if (aColumn == 4) {
      //Find where to display the project's list
      var range = aSheet.getRange(aCell.getRow(), aColumn + 1);
      //Find the name of the category (clients)
      var categoryName = aCell.getValue();
      //Remove spaces for the names (as Named Ranges cant contain special characters or spaces)
      categoryName = categoryName.replace(/\s/g, '');
      //Identify the Named Range based on the category selected
      var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(categoryName);
      setDataValid_(range, sourceRange);
    }
   }

   function setDataValid_(range, sourceRange) {
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(sourceRange, true).build();
    range.setDataValidation(rule);
   }`

I created the following project so you can take a look at how it works:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gUZ-mxwjaiKoc0KcZo8UnFglvyWsC1vpoT6XOLftZDA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Okay but I want to display the 2 select lists in my Google Form... how?